# Japanese Encoding subject in Outlook 07

Tags: unicode, encoding, outlook, office-2007

I am trying to read and process Japanese emails. I have set my regional and language options to East Asian and languages for non-Unicode in the XP control panel. I have to process .pst files and preserve the true metadata and I am having trouble with the subject line and sometimes the to: and cc: fields. I get my message body to show Japanese fine but then I get gibberish in the subject as shown below

```
CC FIELD: cc. ￨ﾨﾈ￧ﾔﾻ￣ﾀﾀ￦ﾝﾉ￥ﾱﾱ￦ﾙﾺ￦ﾁﾒ

SUBJECT FIELD: Re: ä¸‰è±ï¼¬ï¼£ï¼¤æ’¤é€€ã«é–¢ã™ã‚‹æƒ…å ±åŠã³åŒ—ç±³æ¶²æ™¶çŠ¶æ³

MESSAGE BODY: 佐藤さんへ：情報ありがとうございます。この機に是非とも三菱パークをリプレースしたいものです。ところでこのシニアマネージャーはどうされたのですか？内も苦しいですが。

中村マネージャー：ＡＤＩはＣＰＴへ売却打診中とのこと。うーん。
```

I am not a programmer so please simplify any recommendations you have as to how I can fix the subject line. FYI, I am using Outlook 07 Pro, Windows XP Pro and the .pst files are pre-existing so they are being opened via: File-->open outlook data file.

Comment: Paste an example of a message that shows incorrectly - raw, straight from the source.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the header lines contain Japanese characters encoded in ISO-2022-JP without this being specified so, i.e. the emails contained in the PST files are violating the specifications. You may be able to get around this by specifying the encoding manually within the Outlook settings - I don't have Outlook, so I can't tell you where exactly to look. If Outlook does not have that option, then you're pretty much hosed - you'd have to find a Japanese version of Outlook, or a third-party application that can read PST files and allows you to manually set the encoding.

Comment: There was actually a reproducable bug in Outlook 2000 with subject lines (even correctly encoded ones)... maybe it has reappeared?